# Using Scalable Link Interface (SLI) to speed up renders

Tags: workflow

Has anyone used two titan cards in Scalable Link Interface to speed up renders? I'm just curious because I've tried everything.

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5228/how-will-two-gpus-improve-cycles-performance

Comment: SLI will actually hurt performance with cycles.