# Bad GTX 970 Performence

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

i just got my new Zotac GTX 970 and blender 2.73 but i'm worried about my cylcles results. My other card was a GTX 670 OC, so theoreticly i should achieve 50-100% faster rendering times. Sadly the increase turned out to be around 10-20% in direct comparison. My question is: Could anybody tell me if this is normal at the moment; maybe caused by a lag of optimisation? Is someone achieving better results? I'm really worried if the card is worth the extra money :/

I am using:
Win 8.1,
i5 3350p,
8GB

Comment: How does it do on the [benchmark scene](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?239480-2-6x-Cycles-render-benchmark)?

Comment: This always depends one the scene, my 980 is approximately 2.5x faster than my 660. For more samples see http://mad-creations.nl/blenchmark/

Comment: What version of Blender are you using?

Comment: Never mind my comment, somehow I missed the first line!  Sorry.

Comment: have you tried using both cards in tandem? The more gpus the faster cycles will render...

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5228/how-will-two-gpus-improve-cycles-performance/5229#5229

Comment: Try also one of the optimized builds from http://www.graphicall.org/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic ["Hardware faults"](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/6/5113)