# Can you use 2 non SLI GPUs in Blender?

Tags: gpu

Can you use 2 non SLI GPUs  in Blender with 2 different architectures an example
a geforce gtx 560 and a quadro fx 4000.

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5228/how-will-two-gpus-improve-cycles-performance

Comment: SLI makes two GPUS act like one, which will actually make cycles go slower than when using the two GPUs in parallel (without SLI)

Comment: Do note that GTX and Quadro gpus use different drivers, and while using both in the same system work for some, it's not necessarily plug and play and/or problem-free. (According to some internet posters, I have no personal experience.)

Comment: The gtx and quadro cards are examples the actual cards I am wondering about are a geforce gt730 and a geforce 560ti

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one system I use different architectures:

- GTX 660 Ti - Kepler
- GTX 980 -  Maxwell

this does not prove that it will work with all combinations, but as long the drivers support  CUDA (true for both GPUs you listed) it should work fine.