# two gpu's, how to differentiate them in system settings pull down menu?

Tags: rendering, gpu

I have two identical gpu's.  When opening the compute device menu in system settings, there are two identical entries.  I'd like to select the one that isn't being used - is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a trial and error kind of question.
Choose one of the GPUs on the list:

[image]

And do a render test.
Using an external application to monitor the GPU usage you can determine which card is being used to render.

[image]

In my case the one on the bottom of the list in blender is GPU1, but it might be different on your system.

Now, I would recommend enabling both cards to render... Even with the load of the display, it might cut your render time almost in half...

Comment: @cegaton I have a windows/nvidia with a GTX970 card. Is is always possible to install a second GXT970 card ? Now I have started rendering animations I am interested :)

Comment: As long as you have adequate power and cooling in your host computer, you can add multiple GPUs. To use in blender you don't need SLI. read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5228/how-will-two-gpus-improve-cycles-performance/5552#5552