# GPU rendering for Cycles on MAC PRO (late 2013)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, osx

As the development notes of Blender [2.76](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.76/Cycles) tell, there should be support for GPU rendering under OpenCL now and it should be possible to let the AMD GPU's do the Cycles Rendering.
I tried and it seems to work but it is outrageously slow and I will return to my old habit again (modelling at MAC and rendering at a Windows / NVidia machine. Anyone who can explain how to render Cycles with reasonable performance at a Mac Pro? And what can be expected in near future?

Comment: Throw that mac *not*pro out the window and do everything on that nvidia workstation. In the future it can be expected that apple will keep producing overpriced garbage. It's not Blender's fault the rendering on a Mac is so slow..

Comment: @Jerryno I am not blaming Blender. I am just curious if there is anything good to expect from GPU rendering at Mac Pro now or in the near future.

Comment: @cegaton I am not expecting a lot. But somehow I cannot believe that Apple is saying goodbye to the 3D world. As I like the Apple platform I continue to use it for general stuff, Photoshop/Lightroom and I do everything that has heavy GPU tasks on the NVIDIA machine.

Answer (score 2):

The original graphics cards that came with the mac pro's aren't up to much so I'd expect the cpu to render faster. However if like me you want to stick with the mac pro you can get an nvidia card and use their web drivers.

I think there are many PC cards you can put in there (you'll just lose the boot screen). I got a GTX 980 from [Mac Vid Cards](http://www.macvidcards.com) which is awesome to render on. Sometimes I get a CUDA error but generally a restart of blender fixes that.

Another option that I use is [Ray Pump](http://raypump.com). You need to pay but it's really cheap. They've been down for maintenance but I assume they'll be back up soon.

Comment: Sorry, But i have a Mac Pro late 2013 (the cylinder) and I just want to know what is possible with that machine.

Comment: ah sorry. Yeah the fixed AMD cards and inability to sensibly upgrade those machines have kept me with my old 2010 model :) I added a new CPU and the better graphics card and it still runs great for me.

Comment: my old Mac Pro was really old and I wanted to stay at MAC OS X. Also I use the Mac Pro not only for Blender. So I bought the new one (doing the rendering at a NVIDIA machine).

Answer (score 1):

Forget it Mac Pro (new one) is garbage. It also want to buy this thing but as I learned it is not suitable to render GPU I revised my plans. Get a linux station, buy 2 GTX 980 and mem of 32GB. And you have all what this stylish thing DOESN'T have...

Comment: Why do you install two GPU on your Linux machine ? Does Blender render on two GPU's ? I ask because I render on a windows/NVIDIA machine (I do the modelling part on the MAC).

Comment: @JanScherders blender can use multiple GPUs read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5228/how-will-two-gpus-improve-cycles-performance

Comment: @JanScherders as an alternative look into external GPU enclosures that can be hooked up using Thunderbolt.

Comment: @cegaton That is a very interesting option (external GPU). This is really new to me !! Thanks a lot !!