# How to do GPU rendering on MacBook Pro 2016 (AMD Radeon Pro 460)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu, opencl

I'd really like to do GPU render on my new MacBook Pro 2016 with **AMD Radeon Pro 460**, but I get the dreaded **Loading render kernels (may take a few minutes the first time)** problem.

I don't see my GPU on [the list of supported Open CL devices](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/OpenCL) but the list says it's from May 2015. Is there anyone working on getting these devices to work?

However, it shows up fine in Blender settings, and the computer also has Intel HD Graphics 530, and I tried either or both with the same result. Is there perhaps a way to download a render kernel and put it in a folder or anything, or is this computer simply not supported?

[image]

Comment: Laptop/integrated graphics cards, and AMD cards in general have unreliable results with Blender from what I've seen. Hopefully that will change in future, as Blender has received a little funding from AMD. At this time, I don't think that it necessarily will work, or will in the near future.

Comment: A weird thing is that it actually just finished rendering the default scene on GPU. Then I tried again on the BMW-benchmark, and it rendered 25% of the image, and the % slowly increased, but after about 10 minutes, I cancelled it at 9%. Will try again later. So "Loading render kernels" might not be the main issue anymore, I just had to be patient for it to start.

Comment: GPU rendering on a MAC ... forget it. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46936/gpu-rendering-for-cycles-on-mac-pro-late-2013 You can do the modelling on the MAC but GPU rendering .... really forget it

Comment: see also http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66041/why-cant-i-render-smoke-with-my-amd-graphic-card?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I recently got the MacBookPro 2017 Radeon Pro 555 2 GB + Intel HD Graphics 630 1536 MB. Having both GPU on apparently causing Cycles not to render.

Just turning on Radeon Pro 555 and turning off Intel HD Graphics and the Cycles render works.

[image]