# Does enabling crossfire speed up GPU rendering with cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

As the title says, does it help or not to enable crossfire?

Comment: very very related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47904/should-i-run-sli-or-not

Comment: I think Blender in general uses the resources better with independent graphics cards than with crossfire/SLI enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried rendering the bmw with both crossfire enabled and disabled (2 of my 3 cards)

The setup is 
Radeon R9 280X
Radeon R9 270
Radeon 7870

The following time (2.11) is with crossfire enabled between the two R9's

[image: bmw cycles GPU render with crossfire enabled]

while 1.33 was the time with crossfire disabled

[image: bmw cycles GPU render with crossfire enabled]