# Does Blender Cycles support rendering in SLI mode - two and more graphics cards?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

Can we make SLI bridge between our graphics cards for a faster rendering on blender Cycles renderer? I saw on the blender version 2.79.4 we can faster render on 64*64 render tile on CPU and GPUs, together... that is better than just using GPUs... But I believe it would be even faster when we could render in SLI mode...

Comment: Blender works more efficiently when working with each GPU separateley. As far as I know SLI doesn't help you render faster. Splitting the load between CPUs does. But make a test and report back...

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5228/how-will-two-gpus-improve-cycles-performance and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47904/should-i-run-sli-or-not

Answer (score 3):

SLI was designed to be used in accelerating rendering **to display** in supported applications with OpenGL or Direct 3D, by either alternating the frames or splitting the frames between the GPUs. As Blender uses the CUDA engine when rendering, and has built-in support for using several cards simultaneously, there is no benefit from enabling SLI.