# Cycles using only one of 3 GPUs

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

I've been using 3 GTX 1080 cards for more than a year now, for Cycles rendering, but just recently, all of a sudden, Blender is only using one of them, ignoring the other 2 for rendering.

I can see all three in Blender User prefs. The system (Win 10) sees them, it's only just one, being used for rendering.

I've tried different versions of Blender. Even Nightlies. Same thing.

Any help and suggestions more than welcome.
Thank you.

Comment: I assume you're not using an SLI, right?

Comment: They are linked in SLI at the moment, yes

Comment: Don't use SLI... Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5228/how-will-two-gpus-improve-cycles-performance and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108078/does-blender-2-79-cycles-support-rendering-in-sli-mode-two-and-more-graphics-c

Comment: Thanks for that. Sneaky Nvidia must have enabled it when I did a driver update a few days ago! 
All sorted now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use SLI (Scalable Link Interface)

SLI works by linking two or more video cards together to produce a single output, which works to speed up the display in games.

Cycles works better if the load is split using each GPU independently.

Using the Nvidia Control panel you can disable the use of SLI.

[image]