# 2 GPUs but only one render tile

Tags: rendering, gpu

I have two GTX 1080 and for a while when i press F12 blender rendered everything with 2 tiles. Right now no matter what i do there is only one render tile. In system tab in user preferences i can ether select both GPUs or none, does anyone know a solution to this. BTW it is not hardware

Comment: but isn't it not otpimal to use only on or two tiles by GPU renderung? When I want to use both of my quadro 2000 cards, I need to specify it in my nvidea settings (but they don't have SLI)

Comment: Read: [Does Blender Cycles support rendering in SLI mode - two and more graphics cards?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108078/does-blender-2-79-cycles-support-rendering-in-sli-mode-two-and-more-graphics-c)

Answer (score 0):

Someone answered me elsewere.

Turns out you need to have your SLI "DISABLED" which is very confusing since you need to enable that to have better performance in everything else.