# Does Nvidia SLI matter for Blender?

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

Does Nvidia SLI matter for modeling in Blender, rendering in Cycles, rendering in Eevee?

Comment: No, leave it disabled. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5228/how-will-multiple-gpus-improve-cycles-rendering-performance

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos is that the case for eevee as well?

Comment: https://blenderartists.org/t/eevee-sli-crossfire-possibilities/1158208